# TAG <a> not opening the link

Tags: html, css

I've an menu navigation bar in my index.php, I cut only the parts necessary to show what is going on, I've searched thoroughly and didn't find an answer.

This is my index.php and css, I wrote down an page that my website has (incluirCliente.php) and whenever I hover my mouse over Animais and try to click in Incluir the browser doesn't go to incluirCliente.php, doesn't even try to. All it does is stick the page in the index, it doesn't prompt another page saying that it doesn't exist.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  padding: 30px;
}
/* MENU GERAL*/

.nav-main {
  width: 537px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 70px;
  color: gray;
}
/* FIM MENU GERAL*/

/* NOME DA PET SHOP - SE MUDAR NOME MUDA WIDTH .nav-main */

.nav-main .logo {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  line-height: 40px;
}
/* FIM NOEM DA PET SHOP*/

/* LINKS MENU GERAK - ANIMAIS, PRODUTOS... */

.nav-main > ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}
/* FIM LINKS*/

/* N TOCA NISSO v */

.nav-main > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
/* N TOCA NISSO ^ */

/* BLOCO INDIVIDUAL DO MENU - ANIMAIS, PRODUTO...*/

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* FIM BLOCO INDIVIDUAL */

/* N TOCA v */

.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
/* N TOCA ^ */

/* BLOCO INDIVIDUAL DO MENU SECUNDÁRIO - INCLUIR, EDITAR... */

.nav-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightgray;
  max-height: 0;
}
/* FIM BLOCO INDIVIDUAL DO MENU SECUNDÁRIO - INCLUIR, EDITAR... */

/* CONFIG MENU SECUNDÁRIO */

.nav-content a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* FIM CONFIG MENU SECUNDÁRIO */

/* N TOCA v */

.nav-content a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
/* N TOCA ^ */

/* TAMANHO DROPDOWN MENU */

.nav-sub-animais {
  padding: 20px;
}
.nav-sub-produtos {
  padding: 20px;
}
.nav-sub-servicos {
  padding: 20px;
}
.nav-sub-clientes {
  padding: 20px;
}
/* FIM TAMANHO DROPDOWN MENU */

/* DROPDOWN MENU*/

.nav-sub-animais ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 54px;
}
.nav-sub-produtos ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 57px;
}
.nav-sub-servicos ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 55px;
}
.nav-sub-clientes ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 53px;
}
/* FIM DROPDOWN MENU*/

/* ESTILO DROPDOWN MENU */

.nav-sub-animais ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.nav-sub-produtos ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.nav-sub-servicos ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.nav-sub-clientes ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
/* FIM ESTILO DROPDOWN MENU */

/* NEGOCIO DE CLICAR - NEM PENSA EM MUDAR ALGO */

.nav-item:focus {
  background-color: #444;
}
.nav-item:focus ~ .nav-content {
  max-height: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Menu Inical</title>
  <META charset="utf8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="nav-main">
    <div class="logo">PETSHOP</div>

    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item">Animais</a>
        <div class="nav-content">
          <div class="nav-sub-animais">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="incluirCliente.php">Incluir</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Editar</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Listar</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Excluir</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item">Produtos</a>
        <div class="nav-content">
          <div class="nav-sub-produtos">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Incluir</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Editar</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Listar</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Excluir</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item">Serviços</a>
        <div class="nav-content">
          <div class="nav-sub-servicos">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Incluir</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Editar</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Listar</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Excluir</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item">Clientes</a>
        <div class="nav-content">
          <div class="nav-sub-clientes">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Incluir</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Editar</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Listar</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Excluir</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>

</body>
```

Comment: What else did you expect? The link is `<a href="#">Incluir</a>`

Comment: Have you read everything?  Its the one that has incluirCliente.php in the href. I typed only that one as an example

Comment: <a href="#" class="nav-item">Animais</a> then              <li><a href="incluirCliente.php">Incluir</a>

Comment: Does that file exist in the same directory?

Comment: Yes everything is in the same directory, I dunno what else I could do, I tried everything, try to run in your PC with the same code and you'll see it doesn't opeen

Comment: You can see wheen you hover your mouse in the link Incluir on Animais, on the bottom of the browser it shows the page wheere the link leads to, but when you click it, it doesnt open

Comment: You need to prepend ( add in front ) the path to your .php directory,  phpinfo.php in your browser should tell you this.

Comment: You mean add ../incluirCliente.php ? Everything is in the same directory, so they can see each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clicking didn't work because .nav-content get collapsed when .nav-item is not focused.

```
/*.nav-content only open when .nav-item is focused*/
.nav-item:focus ~ .nav-content {
  max-height: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in;
}
```

Add this style to your css.

```
.nav-item ~ .nav-content:hover {
  max-height: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in;
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  padding: 30px;
}
/* MENU GERAL*/

.nav-main {
  width: 537px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  height: 70px;
  color: gray;
}
/* FIM MENU GERAL*/

/* NOME DA PET SHOP - SE MUDAR NOME MUDA WIDTH .nav-main */

.nav-main .logo {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  line-height: 40px;
}
/* FIM NOEM DA PET SHOP*/

/* LINKS MENU GERAK - ANIMAIS, PRODUTOS... */

.nav-main > ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
}
/* FIM LINKS*/

/* N TOCA NISSO v */

.nav-main > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
/* N TOCA NISSO ^ */

/* BLOCO INDIVIDUAL DO MENU - ANIMAIS, PRODUTO...*/

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* FIM BLOCO INDIVIDUAL */

/* N TOCA v */

.nav-item:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
/* N TOCA ^ */

/* BLOCO INDIVIDUAL DO MENU SECUNDÁRIO - INCLUIR, EDITAR... */

.nav-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightgray;
  max-height: 0;
}
/* FIM BLOCO INDIVIDUAL DO MENU SECUNDÁRIO - INCLUIR, EDITAR... */

/* CONFIG MENU SECUNDÁRIO */

.nav-content a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* FIM CONFIG MENU SECUNDÁRIO */

/* N TOCA v */

.nav-content a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
/* N TOCA ^ */

/* TAMANHO DROPDOWN MENU */

.nav-sub-animais {
  padding: 20px;
}
.nav-sub-produtos {
  padding: 20px;
}
.nav-sub-servicos {
  padding: 20px;
}
.nav-sub-clientes {
  padding: 20px;
}
/* FIM TAMANHO DROPDOWN MENU */

/* DROPDOWN MENU*/

.nav-sub-animais ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 54px;
}
.nav-sub-produtos ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 57px;
}
.nav-sub-servicos ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 55px;
}
.nav-sub-clientes ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 53px;
}
/* FIM DROPDOWN MENU*/

/* ESTILO DROPDOWN MENU */

.nav-sub-animais ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.nav-sub-produtos ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.nav-sub-servicos ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.nav-sub-clientes ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
/* FIM ESTILO DROPDOWN MENU */

/* NEGOCIO DE CLICAR - NEM PENSA EM MUDAR ALGO */

.nav-item:focus {
  background-color: #444;
}
.nav-item:focus ~ .nav-content {
  max-height: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in;
}
.nav-item ~ .nav-content:hover {
  max-height: 400px;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in;
  transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Menu Inical</title>
  <META charset="utf8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="nav-main">
    <div class="logo">PETSHOP</div>

    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item">Animais</a>
        <div class="nav-content">
          <div class="nav-sub-animais">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="incluirCliente.php">Incluir</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Editar</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Listar</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Excluir</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item">Produtos</a>
        <div class="nav-content">
          <div class="nav-sub-produtos">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Incluir</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Editar</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Listar</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Excluir</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item">Serviços</a>
        <div class="nav-content">
          <div class="nav-sub-servicos">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Incluir</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Editar</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Listar</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Excluir</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-item">Clientes</a>
        <div class="nav-content">
          <div class="nav-sub-clientes">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Incluir</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Editar</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Listar</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Excluir</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>

</body>
```